# Acentuação php - firebird

Tags: php, mvc, firebird, firebird-2.5

Estou fazendo um módulo web para um sistema antigo que utiliza o Firebird. Fiz a conexão utilizando o PDO, porém quando faço uma consulta utilizando algum caractere especial ele não retorna resultados. Caso não utilize caractere especial a consulta funciona de forma perfeita.

Ele consegue ler os nomes que utilizam caractere especial e mostrar, porém não estou conseguindo consultar com parâmetros especiais.

Estou também em busca da solução através do ibase_connect.

O objetivo é realizar buscas com o "ç" no firebird através do PHP

Comment: Qual a collation do banco?

Answer (score -2):

```
$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:host=hostname;dbname=dados', 'user', 'pass');

$pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o código?